# WCF Ria Silverlight 4, wrong list returned

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have a DataService returning an IQueryable
I breakpoint at the "return" statement, list looks fine.
I breakpoint at the Async callback method, and all the elements in the list are identical objects.

Any Ideas?

Comment: And when you simply bind to a DataGrid do you still see a set of identical rows?  IOW, are you sure that breakpointing and examining data is not itself having a deterimental effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that it was due to incorrect values of the [key] property